# Identifying term for songs with slow stomp bass tempo

Tags: terminology, sound

I have heard songs from many different genres from rock to rap to techno with this same kind of core slow stomping percussion beat. Example songs are:

- [God's Gonna Cut You Down](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IStlBOX9F4o) by Johnny Cash
- [When the Levee Breaks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fOEQTJV_3-w) by Led Zeppelin
- [Off the Grid Pt. 1](http://youtu.be/-6RlIfvAEp8?t=17s) by Mogi Grumbles
- [Think Differently](http://youtu.be/QxAT7W8i03k?t=7s) by Wu-Tang

Is there an identifying term I can use to search for and find more songs like these? Trying to populate a workout playlist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing these tracks all share is a heavy backbeat (percussion hits on 2 and 4 of a 4-beat cycle). That plus a bpm (beats per minute) of just under 60 should get you the sound you want.